# How can I test website content from different US states

Tags: vpn, web, amazon-web-services

I am working on a website that has a set of regular content for pretty much everyone. A few US state governments do not like the phrasing/implications of some of the content and would like to make sure that their states' residents are not able to see the regular content at all. The trouble is that these states are not my home state.

Most VPN solutions that I've found are about spoofing your location to make it appear that you are in a different country, and while many might have server locations in more than one US state, they are not the state(s) that I'm targeting.

Other than traveling to those states, or knowing someone in those states, what kind of options exist to test content as if I'm a resident of another state? I'm essentially looking for a VPN that is (or can be) US state specific, or some equivalent process.

For example, I have a normal corporate VPN, but is it possible to have IT set up alternate VPNs based in those states, such that connecting to "VPN 1" or "VPN 2" would make my traffic appear to be from those places instead of my home state? Would AWS have any kind of service/product that could assist?

Comment: Most cloud VPS providers (e.g. AWS, Rackspace, Digital Ocean, Linode, etc.) have data centers in several states, and offer VPS's in any of their data centers.  You might want to see if one of these providers offers VPS's in the state(s) that you are interested in.  If so, you can open an account with the provider, turn-up a VPS, and deploy a VPN on the VPS.

Comment: How is your site determining the location? If it is browser-based, you can get browser plugins to spoof locations

Comment: @schroeder, the location determination all happens on the servers before the content is loaded. The site is SSR and makes a request to get geolocation info before returning the rendered content.

Comment: @mti2935, these providers, particularly AWS, only have data centers in a couple of states, and not the few we are particularly interested in. The solution I'm looking for should be scalable to any state as we have no upfront idea which will require alternate content.

Comment: @schroeder, location is determined by the IP address of the request.

Comment: And how is the IP is correlated to geographic location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your server is using Geo-IP to determine location, I would simply add some testing IPs to the database and associate them to the locations that you want to test. That way, you can use the IPs that you can control and test your system at your convenience.

No VPNs or fancy routing needed.

Comment: Do remember that geo-ip lookups are far from perfect...

Comment: @LvB right ... but that's why you can be deterministic with adding the specific locale to the specific IP you are using. It's just a straight lookup. The imperfections are about the geoip databases, which is not an issue in my proposal.

Comment: I am not suggesting it was @schroeder, your answer was fine as is. It’s more meant as a word of caution. For anyone implementing my tour proposal.

Comment: This is a good solution, thank you. Unfortunately we have some resource constraints at the moment so the quickest solution for us was to install NordVPN and find a server in the right state (took some trial and error). Nord seemed to have the most locations to choose from and was more than just country specific. I'll select your answer because I feel like if we had time/people to do it, that would've been a better approach overall.